# why inheritance has no standard way in javascript and why it has different ways of defining it and what is the aspect of each one?

Tags: javascript

my question is: why there is difference between all 3 ways of defining inheritance ?
and if the first snippet is the most correct one how people before 2015 dealt with new keyword ?

1. The first snippet the object  y is instance of gorilla and it has the prototype and methods of animal, and animal inherits from object prototype
   NOTE:that name, age are defined on the object itself
2. The second snippet is the same as first snippet but the difference is it has additional properties on the Animal prototype name,age and they both have undefined value duo to new call.
3. The third snippet is whole different it has the prototype of Object and it is like it moved every method from the animal prototype to itself.

---

Consider Looking at these snippets

```js
function Animal(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function () {
  console.log(`${this.name} is eating!`);
};

function Gorilla(name, age, action) {
  Animal.call(this, name, age);
}

Gorilla.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Gorilla.prototype.constructor = Gorilla;

var y = new Gorilla("morphy", 50);
console.log(y);
```

[image: above snippet picture]

```js
function Animal(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function () {
  console.log(`${this.name} is eating!`);
};

function Gorilla(name, age, action) {
  Animal.call(this, name, age);
}

Gorilla.prototype = new Animal();
Gorilla.prototype.constructor = Gorilla;

var y = new Gorilla("morphy", 50);
console.log(y);
```

[image: above snippet picture]

```js
function Animal(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function () {
  console.log(`${this.name} is eating!`);
};

function Gorilla(name, age, action) {
  Animal.call(this, name, age);
}

Gorilla.prototype = Animal.prototype;
Gorilla.prototype.constructor = Gorilla;

var y = new Gorilla("morphy", 50);
console.log(y);
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this more a question of inheritance than polymorphism?

Comment: yea sry i missed up

Comment: "*why inheritance has no standard way in javascript*" - it has (since 2015): `class Gorilla extends Animal { }`. Use a more modern tutorial.

Comment: Would be interesting to know the source of this revelation about "the three ways". Use of `Animal.call()` is questionable and not necessary if you craft inheritance based upon a design (rather than on-the-fly). Setting the prototype first allows you to construct an Gorilla and set property values with `this.`

Comment: @Bergi - you'll get a bunch of pushback from the React fans that insist that "_hooks_" are more important than food - hence they won't use the `class` keyword. :-)

Comment: @Boudyhesham The third way is outright wrong and doesn't work. The second way is what people did before the introduction of `Object.create` in ES5 (2011), and has the drawbacks you noticed. The first way is the proper one.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Sure, but react hooks don't provide prototypical inheritance. (And I'd even argue that they don't do inheritance at all, but rather composition - which is good in their use case, but not important here). React fans wouldn't use constructors and `new` either.

Comment: why this man closed my question as duplication it has nothing to do with benifits of object.create i had one more question well thanks to u @Bergi

Comment: @RandyCasburn so you're saying that Animal.call() is not necessary to establish a super call between the 2 ?

Comment: @Boudyhesham While the title of the canonical topic might not fit yours, it is an exact duplicate, discussing all three approaches you mentioned, and should answer all your questions regarding them. Which question does it not answer?

Comment: the last one u asnwered the third one is not a proper way of defining inheritance

Comment: Please read the QA again then. It's discussed under "*Some say that `Dog.prototype = Animal.prototype;` can also work. So now I'm totally confused*"

Comment: wasn't this ur comment ! `The third way is outright wrong and doesn't work. The second way is what people did before the introduction of Object.create in ES5 (2011), and has the drawbacks you noticed. The first way is the proper one`

Comment: @Boudyhesham - not if you use setters/getters, but never mind as I'm so confused about which version we're discussing - unless you are maintaining code from 2012, do what Bergi says and use `extends` + `super()` - problem solved.